# Using Regex to find values after a specific string of variable length and drop into array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to parse through text files that contain several pieces of data that I need to drop into a growing array.I need to find and store in an array measurements happening after a string that reads "P1".

The values can be either positive or negative (and i need the positive or negative information to be kept with the values), so I can't just set the regex to find blank number of characters after a string because it may vary. Also, the section named "Error" may contain more lines depending on the text file...

Mind you, I have never used regex for anything other than finding certain specific text and returning a true or false value...so I'm very new at this/don't know how to. I was thinking that something could be done to find and store text occurring after "P1:", but I don't know how to do express it.

Any help would be great...I am lost and learning...but it's not happening as fast as I want it to and I'm a little stuck.

Thanks! I appreciate the help.

Elle

Answer (score 0):

This matches the `P1` lines capturing the three numeric values:

```
P1: (-?\d+\.\d+), (-?\d+\.\d+), (-?\d+\.\d+)
```

- `(`…`)` is a capturing group
- `-?` matches an optional `-`
- `\d+` matches one or more digits (0-9)
- `\.` matches a literal `.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your regexp: `^\s*P1:\s+[\-\d\.]+,\s+([\-\d\.]+,\s+[\-\d\.]+)\s*$`

Let's decompose it, so you can learn from this example:

`^` means beginning of the line

`\s*` stands for any leading whitespace characters, you want to ignore them, but they might be there (just a good habit)

`P1:` is what you are looking for

`\s+` is allowing any number of spaces (at least one) between the P1 and the following numbers

`[\-\d\.]+` is the simplest way to detect your number. I'm assuming here the input provided is correct, otherwise I would make it a bit more complicated, like `\-?\d+(\.\d+)?` (this would match numbers like 12, -1, 12.01, -11.21, and well, -0 too)

`,\s+` a comma with one or more spaces follows the first number

`([\-\d\.]+,\s+[\-\d\.]+)` the second and the third number is what you are looking for, and they are separated by a comma and some spaces.

You probably don't need \s+ if you know for sure there's always just one space there. Use space instead, like this: `([\-\d\.]+, [\-\d\.]+)`

`\s*` helps you to ignore any trailing whitespaces.

`$` stands for the end of the line

And here is your code (Perl):

```
while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ m/^\s*P1:\s+[\-\d\.]+,\s+([\-\d\.]+,\s+[\-\d\.]+)\s*$/);
}
```

To make it a bit more universal, make `P1` a parameter;

```
my $pattern="P1"; # or $pattern = shift;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ m/^\s*$pattern\:\s+[\-\d\.]+,\s+([\-\d\.]+,\s+[\-\d\.]+)\s*$/);
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Peter. I appreciate you breaking it down to understand it...really handy. I'm getting more comfortable with it daily, but it helps to see it explained concisely. I'm actually trying to code in C#, but i'm looking into your reply and know that I can try to make sense of it for c#. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what forms the machine generates. If its uniform, possibly all you need to locate the line is `^[^\S\n}*P1:`. It can be expanded to use landmarks, like text around it. This further disambiguates its location.

Modifiers to be used: no-dotall('.' matches all but newlines), multi-line ('^' start of line, '$' end of line).

This asumes you read the entire file into a string. There is no need not to do this using  modern day memory. If you want to do this on a line by line basis, just break appart the regex into alternations where each match is a level that eventually leads to a valid line...  Centration: (level1), E0: (level2), P1: (level3), If level1 && level2 && level3, then valid. Or, whatever.

Compressed

```
^[^\S\n]*Centration:.*\n+^[^\S\n]*E0:.*\n+^[^\S\n]*P1:[^\S\n]*[+-]?[\d.]+[^\S\n]*,[^\S\n]*([+-]?[\d.]+)[^\S\n]*,[^\S\n]*([+-]?[\d.]+)[^\S\n]*$
```

Expanded

```
^ [^\S\n]*  Centration: .* \n+
^ [^\S\n]*  E0: .* \n+
^ [^\S\n]*  P1: [^\S\n]*  [+-]?[\d.]+  [^\S\n]* ,   # distance
                [^\S\n]* ([+-]?[\d.]+) [^\S\n]* ,   # x  - capture grp 1
                [^\S\n]* ([+-]?[\d.]+) [^\S\n]* $   # y  - capture grp 2
```